# Some doubts about the boundary of set $A$ in the ambient space $V$ (in the book: Multidimensional real analysis. 1)

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus

When I reading **Duistermaat J. & Kolk J's Multidimensional real analysis. 1 Differentiation**.(you can read from here: [Multidimensional real analysis. 1](http://books.google.co.jp/books?id=5KXkkGTnaYIC&printsec=frontcover&dq=bibliogroup%3a%22Multidimensional%20Real%20Analysis%22&hl=zh-CN&sa=X&ei=0k71UcD-Go2clQXI8oCIDw&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false))

In page 11. I can't understand the reasoning by author:
Let $V$ be a fixed subset in $\Bbb{R}^n$ and let $A$ be a subset of $V$,then:
$$\partial_VA=(V \cap\overline{A})\cap(V\cap\overline{V\backslash A})=(V \cap\overline{A})\cap(V\cap\overline{\Bbb{R}^n\backslash A})=V\cap(\overline{A}\cap\overline{A^c})=V\cap\partial A$$

---

I don't think $V\cap\overline{V\backslash A} = V\cap\overline{\Bbb{R}^n\backslash A}$, if we set $V=A$, then $V\cap\overline{V\backslash A}=V\cap\emptyset=\emptyset$,but $V\cap\overline{\Bbb{R}^n\backslash A} = V \cap \overline{A^c}=A\cap\overline{A^c}=\partial A \not= \emptyset$
.

Comment: Is $V$ supposed to be open? (Then it would be correct.)

Comment: There's apparently no such condition, hence it's wrong, as your example shows.

Comment: @DanielFischer The author only suppose $V$ is a fixed subset in $\Bbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @DanielFisher says the equality holds if $V$ is open but not generally. Although you're disproving $V ∩ \overline{V \setminus A} = V ∩ \overline{\mathbb{R}^n \setminus A}$ instead of original statement and the last equality $A ∩ \overline{A^c} = ∂A ≠ ∅$ holds surely only if $A$ is closed. You're essentially correct. Let $A = V = $ closed open ball. Then $∂_V A$ is empty since $A = V$, but $V ∩ ∂A = ∂A$ which is the sphere of the ball.